# C programming: function that keeps track of word lengths & counts?

Tags: c, loops

I'm having trouble articulating what the function is supposed to do, so I think I will just show you guys an example. Say my program opens and scans a text file, which contains the following:

"The cat chased after the rooster to no avail."

Basically the function I'm trying to write is supposed to print out how many 1 letter words there are (if any), how many 2 letter words there are, how many 3 letter words, etc.

"
        Length                 Count

```
     2    2
     3    3 
     5    2 
     6    1 
     7    1
```

"

Here's my attempt:

```
int word_length(FILE *fp, char file[80], int count)//count is how many total words there are; I already found this in main()
{
  printf("Length\n");
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while(j < count)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      if(strlen(file[i] = i)
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }//I intended for the for loop to print the lengths
  ++i;
  printf("Count\n");
  while()//How do you print the counts in this case? 
  }
}
```

I think the way I set up the loops causes words of the same length to be printed twice...so it'd look something like this, which is wrong. So how should I set up the loops?

"Length Count

```
     2    1
     2    2
```

"

Comment: Well, the code is completely non functional.

Comment: Given that the code posted doesn't compile, I would suggest you edit your code so that it at the very least compiles correctly!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like homework, so I will not write code for you, but will give you some clues.

1. To hold several values you will need array. Element with index *i* will contain counter for words with length *i*.
2. Find a way to identify boundaries of words (space, period, beginning of line etc.). Then count number of characters between boundaries.
3. Increase relevant counter (see tip 1). Repeat.

Some details. You actually want to *map* one thing to another: length of word to number of such words. For mapping there is special data type, called usually hash(table) or dictionary. But in your case array can perfectly work as a map because you keys are uniform and continues (1,2 ... to some maximum word length).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a single int to count all of that. You need an array and then in it at position 0 you keep track of how many 1 letter words, at position 1 you accumulate 2 letter words and so on.

Comment: So would I use a 2D array in this case?

Comment: Hmm...then two single-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Why two? You said you need to count how many words of 1 letter there are, and of 2 letters and so on. For this task you only need one array, and its size should be as the longest possible word.